# Several gitlab & svn project migration into one gitlab project

Tags: git, svn, merge, gitlab, migration

Mission : Migration 2 svn project and 1 git project into 1 new git project.
( To make it simple, let's call the projects as "svn/first" , "svn/second" and "git/third". )

Condition : Inconsistent folder structure and programming language

| Projects | language | location of Target project | note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| svn/first | C | .trunk/ | First project |
| svn/second | C++ | .trunk/{Target project}/ | Integrate with C++ base Data managing System |
| git/third | C++ | .Project package/{Target project}/ | Integrate with packaging system including database |

How can I migrate beautifully?

In detail, how can I use `$ git svn fetch` or something to migrate 'svn/second' on the project which 'svn/first' is migrated. If this is possible, I think last would be easier.

For your information, the work progress until now is as follows.

1. copy the 'svn/first' history on the parents directory.

   ```
    $ git svn clone
   ```
2. change each file directories to '.Project package/{Target project}/.'

   ```
    $ git mv
   ```
3. merge the last rev of 'svn/first' with the first rev of 'svn/second', manually.

- The source file contents is nearly same, so I changed the extension of file and a little difference of source.

  ```
    $ git mv
  ```

4. But, I am struggling with my ignorance here.. How can I put(add) the 'svn/second' history on the 'svn/first' history, continually.

As I know, git can trace rename work but svn can't. But if not, you can tell me how to rename the file and patch 'svn/second' history on 'svn/first'.

( To be honest, I'd rather feel at ease if it's just impossible. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would split this migration into 2 steps:

1. i would transform all into separate git repositories, with their own project etc, like

- git/first
- git/second
- git/third

2. i would check out the repository, which will be my main project i will extend with the others and integrate the others into it. This can be easily done, as git is dezentralized and you can have multiple remotes.

   Todo achieve this, first check out the first repository

   ```
    git clone <first url>
   ```

   next you can add additional remotes

   ```
    git remote add second <second url>
    git remote add third <third url>
   ```

   now lets say, i want to integrate the `develop` branch, than i would check out all 3 develop branches into different local branches

   ```
    git checkout -b develop --track origin/develop
    git checkout -b develop_second --track second/develop
    git checkout -b develop_third --track third/develop
   ```

   After that i can go to each of the develop branches, apply my changes, like moving etc. commit it locally and merge it into my develop branch.

   Last but not least you need to merge those branches together. You will get an error that the histories are not the same but with `--allow-unrelated-histories` you can surpass this.

   ```
     git switch develop
     git merge develop_second --allow-unrelated-histories
     git merge develop_third --allow-unrelated-histories
   ```

   This way you are migrating also the Git History of all three repositories in the decided branch.

I hope this helps you somehow, and eases your migration, and solves your problem. At least that is how i would tackle it or already tackled it multiple times.

Comment: It sounds like a cliche, but I'm really grateful.

As you advised,

1. Cloned all three svn and git projects to three separated git projects.
2. Leaved only MAIN FOLDER which need to be version controlled.
3. Prepared git/first C project to merge with git/second C++ project.
4. Migrated all project one by one, using <--allow-unrelated-histories> and plus <-Xignore-space-at-eol> options.

It seems little bit inefficiently, but the important thing is that.. I made it!

Again, Thank you very much.

Comment: please do not forget to accept the answer :) if it really helped you